# Two boxes in a row in mobile version col-xs-6 not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3. I have four boxes in a row in desktop version. But I want two boxes in a row in mobile version so I used col-xs-6 but this thing doesn't work. I am new to bootstrap, can you guys help me out.

This is my mobile version [image]

I want like this, two boxed in a row in mobile version [image]

My HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12" id="middleBoxMargin">
<div id="middleBox">
<div id="groupInsurance" class="col-xs-6 group-insurance"></div>
<div id="lifeInsurance" class="col-xs-6 life-insurance"></div>
<div id="dentalInsurance" class="col-xs-6 dental-insurance"></div>
<div id="replacementInsurance" class="col-xs-6 replacement-insurance"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
#middleBoxMargin {
    margin-top: 80px;
}

#middleBox {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

#groupInsurance {
    float: left;
    width: 145px;
    height: 125px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#lifeInsurance {
    float: left;
    width: 145px;
    height: 125px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#dentalInsurance {
    float: left;
    width: 145px;
    height: 125px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#replacementInsurance {
    float: left;
    width: 145px;
    height: 125px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make changes in your code like this.

```css
#middleBoxMargin {
    margin-top: 80px;
}

#middleBox div {
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#middleBox > div div {
  margin:0 auto;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

#groupInsurance {
    width: 145px;
    height: 145px
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#lifeInsurance {

    width: 145px;
    height: 145x;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#dentalInsurance {
    width: 145px;
    height: 145px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    text-align: center;

    cursor: pointer;
}

#replacementInsurance {
    width: 145px;
    height: 145px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12" id="middleBoxMargin">

<div id="middleBox" class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6">
<div id="groupInsurance" class=" group-insurance"></div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6">
<div id="lifeInsurance" class=" life-insurance"></div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6">
<div id="dentalInsurance" class=" dental-insurance"></div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6">
<div id="replacementInsurance" class="replacement-insurance"></div>

</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you going to use bootstrap Grid just remove all specific Widths added for you containers :-

for desktop use col-md-4

for Mobile screen col-xs-6 `<div id="groupInsurance" class="col-md-4 col-xs-6"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

if you use Bootstrap grid you can remove width in css

```
width: 145px;
```

you overwrite bootstrap css